# How do I store HTML/XHTML in an XML file and then use XSLT to retrieve it?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have an xml file containing the documentation from a project of mine. I'm using XSLT to transform this XML file into HTML to output it in a browser.

Now the thing is that I have some entities that contain some html code. Nothing complicated, just some `
 tags. But I don't seem to be able to make it work. I have tried "disable-output-escape" but it only works in internet explorer.

Now I'm trying with namespaces. I wrote this in my root tag.

```
xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
```

and then changed my `<br/>` tags to `<h:br/>`, but now the tags don't appear and I still don't have the line break.

I assume I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my mistake. Had to use copy-of instead of value-of.